# In Elm, how can I detect the mouse position relatively to an html element?

Tags: elm, mousemove, onmousemove

I would like to know the mouse position relatively to an html element. I would also know the size of the element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is possible to detect the mouse position with mouseMove event. This is an example of how it can be implemented using The Elm Architecture.

The view:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ img
            [ on "mousemove" (Decode.map MouseMove decoder)
            , src "http://..."
            ]
            []
        ]
```

The decoder:

```
decoder : Decoder MouseMoveData
decoder =
    map4 MouseMoveData
        (at [ "offsetX" ] int)
        (at [ "offsetY" ] int)
        (at [ "target", "offsetHeight" ] float)
        (at [ "target", "offsetWidth" ] float)
```

The type alias

```
type alias MouseMoveData =
    { offsetX : Int
    , offsetY : Int
    , offsetHeight : Float
    , offsetWidth : Float
    }
```

And the Message

```
type Msg
    = MouseMove MouseMoveData
```

And this is how the data arrive to the Update:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        MouseMove data ->
            -- Here you can use your "data", updating
            -- the model with it, for example
            ( { model | zoomMouseMove = Just data }, Cmd.none )
```

This is a library that does a similar thing: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mbr/elm-mouse-events/1.0.4/MouseEvents